# Nested-loop Inside Append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to make two loops from one data point to create multiple divs.

Data Example:

```
let data = [
  [
    {
        title: '1'
    },
    {
        title: '2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
        title: '3'
    },
    {
        title: '4'
    }
  ]
];
```

If I loop in here, I get 2 arrays with 2 sets of obj each.

I need to append a parent div for each array and inside the appended div, loop again to append the information from the obj.

To look something like this:

```
<div class="first-array"> //Class is just for reference
  <span>
    <p>title</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <p>title</p>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="second-array"> //Class is just for reference
  <span>
    <p>title</p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <p>title</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

How can I be able to achieve this?

Comment: `<p>title</p>` or `<p>1</p>`, `<p>2</p>`, etc? Also, `<p>` should **not** be within `<span>`

Comment: Use nested loops. The outer loop processes the outer array and creates the `div` elements. The inner loop processes the inner arrays and creats the `span` and `title` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to wrap each nested item's `title` property in the appropriate tags, then use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert the array to a string:

```js
let data=[[{title:"1"},{title:"2"}],[{title:"3"},{title:"4"}]];

const HTML = data.map(e => '<div>'+e.map(f => `<span><p>${f.title}</p></span>`).join('')+'</div>').join('')

console.log(HTML);

document.write(HTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) can take an array of objects so you can [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your original data to the structure you want

```js
let data = [[{"title":"1"},{"title":"2"}],[{"title":"3"},{"title":"4"}]]

$(document.body).append(data.map(titles =>
  $("<div>").append(titles.map(({ title: text }) =>
    $("<span>").append($("<p>", { text }))))))
```

```css
div, span, p {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  position: relative;
}
div:after, span:after, p:after {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: gray;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div:after { content: "div"; }
span:after { content: "span"; }
p:after { content: "p"; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```